# How to catch sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException?

Tags: java, exception

How to catch the following exception that is printed to the error console when trying to load a corrupted PNG file:

```
sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException: invalid depth
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Following code makes the above output appear in the error console. But the exception is never caught:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class TestBadPNG
  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        try
          {
            new ImageIcon(new byte[] { -119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, });
          }
        catch (Exception e)
          {
            // This line will not be reached.
            System.err.println("Bad image.");
          }
      }
  }
```

Probably the image should be loaded in a different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with *ImageIcon* but you could simply first try to create an image from your source (your *byte[]* array) and *then*, if everything goes fine, create the *ImageIcon*.

Like this:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bas = new ByteArrayInputStream( new byte[] { -119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, } );
    Image img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read( bas );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ... // You'll catch that one should it happen...
    }
```

and then if everything goes fine your create the ImageIcon:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon( img );
```

Comment: @Andrej: also if you want to read another answer I made concerning the various BMP and PNG image formats (and others) and why sometimes despite the "file extension" / "file type" you still cannot decode it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220567/why-doesnt-imageio-read-a-bmp-file-until-it-is-re-saved-in-ms-paint/8220966#8220966

Comment: @Andrej if an answer solves your problem, accept it! :D

Answer (score 0):

This Exception is thrown from a separate thread, not the main thread.
Actually your application execution completes successfully.

Comment: @Andrej You can reassign the standard error stream using System.setErr(), but of course, this will redirect all error messages.

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeNakis said, a new `Thread` is spawned. In fact, `ImageIcon` delegates the image loading to a `MediaTracker` which has a spawned  `Thread` and exposes methods to `ImageIcon` to get image status

Try using `getImageLoadStatus()` which returns the underlying status of the image in the `MediaTracker`

You can not get rid of the exception, as exceptions are catched by the `MediaTracker̀
and sent to sytem err. By the way, there is probably a mean to redirect system err elsewhere and keep your app console clean