# Why is my BufferedImage from a byte array returning null?

Tags: java, image

Basically, what I'm doing is converting an image into a byte array, processing it, then after obtaining the byte array, converting it back to an image. Here is how I convert it the byte array to an image.

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(result); //result is the byte array
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert;
try {
   bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
   ImageIO.write(
      bImageFromConvert, watermark_ext, new File(extracted_name_path));
} catch (Exception e) {
   return e.getMessage();
}
```

Now this code works perfectly for PNG or JPG images, however when I use it for BMP images, it returns an exception that says bImageFromConvert is null. Can anyone please help me know why it does that? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream%29):

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied
>   ImageInputStream with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among
>   those currently registered. If no registered ImageReader claims to be
>   able to read the stream, null is returned.

This [previous post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220567/why-doesnt-imageio-read-a-bmp-file-until-it-is-re-saved-in-ms-paint) is more detailed.

The method [javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageReadersBySuffix%28java.lang.String%29) may be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! The previous post is very informative. I'll comment again after trying these new information.

Comment: For future readers of this question, I have solved this. Before restoring the image, I perform some modifications to the byte array. For restoring the bmp image, I didn't do anything to it. That solved it. Thanks Aubin.

Comment: @Lights mind sharing the modifications you made , even thought 3 years have passed.