# Java ImageIO is reading RGB instead of ARGB data

Tags: java, image, pixel, bmp

I'm working on a GUI for a photo editor and currently I'm stuck on loading a 32bit BMP image from a file. It was all going smoothly until I've started experimenting with multiple layers and molding them into a single one. (Layer molding and image saving is beeing done by Runtime class using c++ .exe file)

I've made a simple 300x300 red bmp image using pixelFormer software with individual pixels having values of R:255 G:0 B:0 A:125

What I've noticed is that my method which is bellow loads a RGB with default 255 value for alpha channel where 125 should be. Here it is:

```
public void readFile(String sourceFileName, Image image) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Short> pixels = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

       BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(sourceFileName));
       System.out.println(img.getType());

        for (int i =0;i<img.getHeight();i++)
            for (int j =0;j<img.getWidth();j++)
            {
                Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(j,i),true);
                pixels.add((short)(c.getRed()));
                pixels.add((short)(c.getGreen()));
                pixels.add((short)(c.getBlue()));
                pixels.add((short)(c.getAlpha()));
                System.out.println("argb: " + c.getAlpha() + ", " + c.getRed() + ", " + c.getGreen() + ", " + c.getBlue());
                

            }


      image.loadLayer(new Layer(img.getHeight(),img.getWidth(),pixels));

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        //
    }
```

However, when I load this same BMP file with a c++ reader which I have previously written and save the read data in to a json file I can clearly see that alpha value of 125 is located where Java method returns a 255.

Json partial snippet:
[You can clearly see that pixels are in fact as they should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZOsk.jpg)

I could create a c++ executable for loading the file and run it from Java using Runtime class but I don't want to use that class too often here.

Update: For some reason System.out.println(img.getType()); returns TYPE_INT_RGB

Update 2: For those of you who might thing that I was using some c++ library, no here is my code based on code from  this website: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/11/19/cpp-reading-writing-bmp-images/
Image, Layer and Pixel are my custom classes.

Header structs:

```
    #define BMPID 0x4D42
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct BMPFileHeader {
    uint16_t fileType = BMPID; 
    uint32_t fileSize = 0; //in bytes
    uint16_t unused1 = 0;
    uint16_t unused2 = 0;
    uint32_t data_offset = 0;           // Start position of pixel data (bytes from the beginning of the file)
};

struct BMPInfoHeader {
    uint32_t headerSize = 0; 
    int32_t width = 0; 
    int32_t height = 0; 

    uint16_t planes = 1; //
    uint16_t bitsPerPixel = 0;
    uint32_t compression = 0;
    uint32_t image_size = 0;
    int32_t x_pixels_per_meter = 0;
    int32_t y_pixels_per_meter = 0;
    uint32_t colors_used = 0;
    uint32_t colors_important = 0;    // No. of colors used for displaying the bitmap. If 0 all colors are required
};

struct BMPColorHeader {
    uint32_t red_mask = 0x00ff0000;         
    uint32_t green_mask = 0x0000ff00;      
    uint32_t blue_mask = 0x000000ff;        
    uint32_t alpha_mask = 0xff000000;       
    uint32_t color_space_type = 0x73524742;
    uint32_t unused[12] = { 0 };       // Unused data for sRGB color space
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Actual reader:

```
    void BMPFormater::read(std::string sourceFileName)
{
    {
        std::ifstream input{ sourceFileName, std::ios_base::binary };
        if (input)
        {
           

            BMPFileHeader fileHeader; // struct instance
            BMPInfoHeader infoHeader; // struct instance
            BMPColorHeader colorHeader; // struct instance

            uint32_t row_stride{ 0 };

            input.read((char*)&fileHeader, sizeof(fileHeader));
            if (fileHeader.fileType != BMPID) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Error! Unrecognized file format.");
            }

            input.read((char*)&infoHeader, sizeof(infoHeader));

            this->bitsPerPixel= infoHeader.bitsPerPixel;
           this->height=infoHeader.height;
           this->width=infoHeader.width;

            if (infoHeader.height < 0)
                throw std::runtime_error("The program can treat only BMP images with the origin in the bottom left corner!");

            // Jump to the pixel data location
            input.seekg(fileHeader.data_offset, input.beg);


           this->pixels.resize(this->width * this->height * this->bitsPerPixel / 8);

            // Here we check if there is a need to take into account row padding
            if (infoHeader.width % 4 == 0)
                input.read((char*)this->pixels.data(), this->pixels.size());

            else {
                row_stride = infoHeader.width * infoHeader.bitsPerPixel / 8;

               // uint32_t new_stride = 0;
                uint32_t new_stride = row_stride;
                    while (new_stride % 4 != 0)
                        new_stride++;
                

                std::vector<uint8_t> padding_row(new_stride - row_stride);

                for (int y = 0; y < infoHeader.height; ++y) { //cita red po red i svaki red peduje
                    input.read((char*)(this->pixels.data() + row_stride * y), row_stride);
                    input.read((char*)padding_row.data(), padding_row.size());
                }

            }



            //zamena crvenog i plavog piksela BGR(A) -> RGB(A)
            if (infoHeader.bitsPerPixel == 32)
            {
                
                for (int i = 0; i < infoHeader.width * infoHeader.height * infoHeader.bitsPerPixel / 8; i += 4)
                {
                    uint8_t temp = this->pixels[i];
                    this->pixels[i] = this->pixels[i + 2];
                    this->pixels[i + 2] = temp;
                }

               
            }
            else if (infoHeader.bitsPerPixel == 24)
            {
                
                for (int i = 0; i < infoHeader.width * infoHeader.height * infoHeader.bitsPerPixel / 8; i += 3)
                {
                    uint8_t temp = this->pixels[i];
                    this->pixels[i] = this->pixels[i + 2];
                    this->pixels[i + 2] = temp;
                }
                
            }
            
            Layer newLayer(this->height,this->width,this->bitsPerPixel,this->pixels);

            if (image->numberOfLayers != 0)
           
                image->resizeLayers(newLayer);

            image->layers.push_back(newLayer);
            image->numberOfLayers++;

            input.close();
        }
        else {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open the input image file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the involvement of C++ was tangential so I removed the tag. This is a `java` problem, not a `c++` problem.

Comment: *However, when I load this same BMP file with a c++ reader* -- Even if the C++ tag remained, this wouldn't be enough information anyway.  You would need to mention the library that C++ used to read the image, as there is no "C++ image reader" class in standard C++.  Maybe start there, to see if the library you used has features that the stock ImageIO does not have.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is not a library it is a class which I wrote myself. It is essentialy reading the whole BMP, first the header and then actual pixel values.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220567/why-doesnt-imageio-read-a-bmp-file-until-it-is-re-saved-in-ms-paint/9722527#9722527. Doesn't give a solution, but does give a possible explanation why it doesn't work.

Comment: @kosingas *...features that the stock ImageIO does not have.* -- Look at the link above.  The difference with the C++ code you linked to is that it is low-level and can control everything, while ImageIO you're relying on an API to support the format you're trying to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user @camickr I've found the issue. The API didn't understand this BMP Format (header data most likely) so I've done a conversion from BMP to BMP using this website
https://www.media.io/image-converter.html and it worked out just fine.